# How do I get <pre>..</pre> block in restructured text?

Tags: html, restructuredtext

I've been looking for a while now, without finding what I want. That's why I'm asking you.

I've tried

```
|   text
|   again
```

but it doesn't keep the space at the beginning, so I cant do that :

```
|  text
|      text
|    text
```

Same problem with `::`
So I'm looking for the equivalent of `<pre>` in HTML. Thx for help

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS If you've found a duplicate question on the site, be sure to flag it and leave a link to the dup in your comment so that it can be closed as such. I did a quick search and certainly can't find one --- this question is about ReStructuredText, not HTML. I'd also suggest you take a look at our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) --- even if you mean well, telling someone to search the site they're on without providing any additional help is unfriendly and not welcome behaviour here.

Comment: When you simply state in your question that you searched or "I've been looking for a while now", it is of no value to anyone.  Help me, help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literal blocks in ReStructuredText either need to be *indented* or *quoted*.

You're using the indented form, and in [the specification](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#literal-blocks) we can see how the issue arises:

> Indented literal blocks are indicated by indentation relative to the surrounding text (leading whitespace on each line). **The minimum indentation will be removed from each line of an indented literal block.**

Try using the quoted style instead. For example, if you use

```
>    text
>    again
```

then the whitespace will be kept, but of course this means that you do need to add the `>` character to the start of each line --- as far as I am aware there is no direct equivalent to the HTML `<pre>` tag in which the markup is *completely* left alone.

Comment: Thank for responding so quickly. I suspected  there was no equivalent to `<pre>`.
Anyway, do you think that

   `.. row:: html`
          `<pre> ...`
          `</pre>`

Is one of the solutions ?

Comment: @ZzFlooo Absolutely, including a `<pre>` tag via a `raw` directive could defintely work!

Comment: Glad I could help :)